# SQL query by block of time

Tags: sql, report

I am trying to pull a report from my DB ( mySQL ).

From 9am to 9pm.

By schema has the dates in DATETIME ( MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS )

``` SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name
WHERE date_created BETWEEN '09:00:00' AND '21:00:00'
```

thoughts? Do I have to cast the DATETIME into something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to just get the hours:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, date_created) BETWEEN 9 AND 21
```

Comment: This didn't work for MariaDB( MySQL ) so I changed it to
    WHERE HOUR(date_created) BETWEEN 9 AND 21